# iPad Mini won't turn on

Tags: ipad

I have an iPad Mini that I have had sense the fall.  This morning I woke up and it was working fine.  Now it won't turn on.  I've tried all the regular fixes and nothing is working.  Will the manufacturer warranty cover this?  Should I take it to an Apple store?

Comment: You tried pushing and HOLDING the power button on the side? If the device is turned OFF, as opposed to sleep, it takes a few seconds of pressing for the power to kick in.

Comment: If you can't get it working, then yes, it will be covered by the warranty and you should take it to an Apple store.

Answer (score 2):

Could the battery be dead? If so it may take 5 to 10 minutes hooked up to a wall charger before it will have enough power to reboot. Make sure you use the provided wall charger as most USB chargers don't have enough power and take a very long time to recharge iPads.

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice if you could expand on 'regular fixes'. There are multiple reasons why your ipad would not turn on:

1. Hold both home & lock buttons for 5 seconds, this will force reboot an ios devise and can bring it back to life.
2. Dead battery, leave it charging for 15 minutes. Even standard ipad chargers take a little time to bring it back to life.
3. If none of the above worked it would be a good idea to take it to an apple store and see if they can do anything about it. If the ipad is not old as yours all costs should be covered by a warranty.

From personal experience I can say that once I left mine in car on a hot day where it baked to death. So I had to replace a charging part. If those 'regular fixes' won't work book an appointment and head to an apple store where you will get professional help.